# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseCore" in Flutter Project

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseCore":
      In Podfile:
        firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`) was resolved to 2.4.0, which depends on
          Firebase/CoreOnly (= 10.3.0) was resolved to 10.3.0, which depends on
            FirebaseCore (= 10.3.0)

        google_ml_kit (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_ml_kit/ios`) was resolved to 0.6.0, which depends on
          GoogleMLKit/LinkFirebase (~> 2.2.0) was resolved to 2.2.0, which depends on
            MLKitLinkFirebase (~> 1.3.0) was resolved to 1.3.0, which depends on
              FirebaseCore (~> 8.0)
```

I am getting this error after added firebase to my project.

Here is my PodFile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do

  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

I've tried several steps to fix:

- flutter clean
- flutter build ios
- pod install
- pod update
- pod repo update
- pod install --repo-update

And also:

- delete Pods
- delete Podfile.lock
- Then pod install

It doesn't fix the error

Answer (score 0):

It might be some dependencies is missing.
Have you tried `flutter pub add firebase_core`, `flutter pub get` or `flutter pub upgrade`

Comment: Yes I've tried that